# chapterprefix option not working in scrbook class

Tags: header-footer, chapters

The chapter prefix option that should display "Chapter 1" on the top of chapter name is not coming. I am a beginner with latex so can not find out what is wrong with my code. Please help.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc, a4paper, 11pt, oneside, chapterprefix=TRUE, sfdefaults=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%% Header Footer begin
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\bfseries\small}
\ohead{\headmark}
\lefoot*{\pagemark{} \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} Page}
\rofoot*{Page \rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip} \pagemark}
\ifoot*{\ac{MAKAUT, WB}}
\AddToHook{cmd/frontmatter/after}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}% instead of plain → manual
  \pagestyle{empty}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}%
  \pagestyle{headings}%
}
%%%%%%%%%Header Footer End

\usepackage[pass,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % for underline with normalem option
\usepackage{ragged2e} % For justified text
%\usepackage[none]{./UbuntuFonts/ubuntu}
% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage{multicol}% used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newenvironment{calligraphic}{\usefont{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}}{}

% Link setup
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
  urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
  linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
  citecolor   = red %Colour of citations
}

%\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\include{copyright}
%\include{dedication}
%\include{certificate}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
%\include{acronyms}
%\include{Acknowledgement}
%\include{Publications Related to Thesis}
%\include{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{justify}
In recent years, the rapid advancement of the Internet of Things (IoT) has revolutionized various industries, and one of the most promising applications lies in healthcare, especially for the senior citizen population. With the global population aging at an unprecedented rate, the need for innovative solutions to cater to the healthcare needs of elderly individuals has become increasingly pressing. This thesis focuses on the development of IoT-based healthcare systems tailored for senior citizens, addressing critical challenges such as mobility assistance, fall detection, and fall prevention.\\
The first component of this thesis revolves around the creation of a low-cost smart walking assistant, designed to enhance the mobility and independence of seniors. By incorporating sensor-based technology, this system aims to provide real-time support and feedback to elderly individuals during their daily walks, ensuring a safer and more confident experience.\\
The second aspect of this thesis tackles the specific issue of fall detection, which is particularly pertinent for patients with Parkinson's disease. Through the utilization of smartphone-based sensors and intelligent algorithms, a fall detection system will be developed, offering timely alerts to caregivers or medical professionals, ultimately reducing the fear of falling and enhancing the overall quality of life for Parkinson's patients.\\
Lastly, the thesis delves into the creation of an indigenous fall prevention system, specially designed to address the unique needs of senior citizens. This system, characterized by its affordability and ease of use, aims to empower elderly individuals in preventing falls, thereby mitigating potential injuries and improving their sense of security.\\
In conclusion, this thesis endeavors to contribute to the well-being of senior citizens by presenting low-cost, sensor-based, and user-friendly IoT solutions, focusing on enhancing mobility, reducing fear of falling, and preventing falls. These innovations hold great promise in improving the quality of life for lonely seniors, while also providing caregivers and healthcare professionals with valuable tools to monitor and assist this vulnerable population.

\section{Motivation}
\lipsum[3-5]
Write Motivation of the research work
\section{Contribution}
\lipsum[5-6]
Write the thesis contribution
\section{Organization of thesis}
\lipsum[2-3]
Brief description of chapters in the thesis.
\subsection{Chapter 2: Literature Survey}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 3:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 4:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 5:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 6:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Chapter 7:}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{justify}
\backmatter
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Using `\setcounter{page}{1}` after `\frontmatter` is useless. Please always [reduce the document preamble of your examples to the relevant code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Never use `\\ ` as paragraph delimiter. Int he example, `\mainmatter` already has `\pagestyle{headings}`. So using `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` immediately after `\mainmatter` is useless …

Comment: … [If you don't want first line indent for paragraphs, KOMA-Script provides options and commands to change the paragraph setting](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/). Justified text is the default of the KOMA-Script classes. You don't need to use an extra environment. Note also, that `justify` environment adds extra vertical space and allows page breaks before. You should not use it for almost the whole document but only small passages. An (in your case also not needed) alternative would be command `\justifying`, that would not have those sideeffects.

Comment: Thanks again cabohah

Comment: Off-topic: Loading package `url` (without option) immediately before `hyperref` is useless. Except for some packages for which something else is explicitly documented, `hyperref` should be loaded after all other packages, i.e., after package `float`. `mathtools` also loads `amsmath`, so explicitly loading `amsmath` makes no sense. And several more similar. So cleaning up the document preamble would be recommended also for your real document.

Comment: @cabohah I donot have enough knowledge to clean/ re-arrange the packages. May be I should open a new question, once I finish with the skeleton structure. In the mean time I am following your instruction above. BTW, any help on the page number issue on the other thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is `chapterprefix=true`, i.e. lowercase.